# How to switch data display in UI of 2.7 back to 2.6 style?

Tags: interface

is there a way to make 2.7x version of blender to display numbers-data in fields like x/y/z etc. like in 2.6x version of blender?  Make all data appeal at center, not like in 2.7 new style, when for example in location tabs “x” is always at the left and numeric value is at the right? Thank you.

Comment: Afaik there is no user preference for this. If it means so much to you, just use 2.6.

Comment: If you *really* don't like it, it's pretty easy to compile the latest version of blender with it.

Comment: damn it. Why responsible people decide to change aliment any way? Since 2.4 it was center aligned and this is ergonomically and human friendly. Now when I work I got constant headache trying to grasp on a glance a data, getting only empty space in a middle of a tabs instead. People who decide to change center alignment understand nothing from psychology of perception!